# grep get matched text's filename and line number in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I want to do a `grep` in bash on a folder searching for the term `foobar`. I then want to output all of the matches along w/ the **filename** and **line number** where the occurrences were found. Is this possible?

I need the output to look like:

```
{{filename}}:{{line_number}} - {{matched_text}}
```

Comment: Have you read the man page for `grep`?

Comment: I have but obviously I must have missed something...care to enlighten me?

Comment: You want the -n and -r options.

Comment: You want the -n option.  You only want the -r option if you want to recursively search subdirectories too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grep -nrH 'regex' /dir/
```

`-H` is the option that adds filenames, `-n` adds line numbers, `-r` is recursive

I get filenames even without the `-H` unless there's only one file.

Add `-i` for case-insensitive

Add `-E` for extended regular expressions

Answer (score 3):

Use the -n or --line-number option

```
grep -n foobar
```

Comment: That only returns the line number and not the name of the file it's contained in

Comment: I'm using grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1 and it shows both the file and line number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; try:
`grep -nr "expression" /path/to/files/`

Comment: That only returns the line number and not the name of the file it's contained in

Comment: You may or may not want to use the -r option depending on whether you wish to recursively read files within each subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` based solution:

```
awk '/REGEX/{print FILENAME":"FNR" - "$0}' PATH
```

For a recursive path search,

```
find PATH-TO-START -type f -exec awk '/REGEX/{print FILENAME":"FNR" - "$0}' {} \;
```